# How to convert px from photoshop to css

Tags: css, photoshop, font-size

I saw that a lot of people have an issue with photoshop font-size but I didn't find anything about my problem.

I recently converted my preferences from PT to PX for font size but there was no difference.

My problem is that I have some text set to 30px on photoshop but it seems to be like 16px on CSS.
This is really annoying to convert a psd template to a coded website because i have no clue how it is converted..

Did anybody else already encounter this issue and fix it?

(my file is set to 72dpi, I also tried with 96dpi but nothing changed, and I visualize my file at 100%)

Thx for your answers and sorry if I made some english mistakes.

Comment: what is the size of your screen and your document?

Comment: 24"(1920x1080)- 1326x3000 at 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/POU1b.jpg

Theses params was set by default at 60% so my fonts was 40% tinyer that it should be.
Now 30px is a real 30px :)